# Arduino JSON parsing example

Tags: php, json

I have a problem and hopefully you can help me :)

```
$valueMaxHum= $_POST['valueMaxHum'];
$valueMinHum= $_POST['valueMinHum']; 
$fileHum = fopen("dataSaved/hum.json", "w") or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fileHum, '{"maxHum":$valueMaxHum, "minHum":$valueMinHum}');
fclose($fileHum);
```

I want to replace $valueMaxHum with its value in .json file but only that is written in the file:

{"maxHum":$valueMaxHum, "minHum":$valueMinHum}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've wrapped the whole string in `'` so it is reading the entire thing as a string. In the below, I've closed the `'` wrapping, incorporated the variable, then reopened the `'`.

`fwrite($fileHum, '{"maxHum":'.$valueMaxHum.', "minHum":'.$valueMinHum.'}');`